# jquery change event on checkboxes with class or another calss

Tags: jquery

To write a function handled change event on checkboxes with a class or another class.
The following my code doesn't work.

```
$("table tbody").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]:is('.cbox1, .cbox2')", function (e) {   
//do something
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as i know, i dont heard about a selector called `:is()` in jquery..

Comment: It should be: `"input[type=checkbox].cbox1, input[type=checkbox].cbox2"`

Comment: Yes I know, but I would like to know the same way like that usage of `is()`.

Comment: @suninsky There isn't unless you filter it inside handler

Comment: @A. Wolff So I need to filter or check inside function?

Comment: @suninsky Ya, using as target selector `input[type=checkbox]` and inside handler, e.g: `if(!$(this).is('.cbox1, .cbox2')) return;` and relevant logic following it. Or use as target selector my first comment above

Comment: ok I will check your first comment, sorry I missed it

Answer (score 2):

There is not `:is`. Use the below instead:

```
$("table tbody").on("change", "input[type=checkbox][class^=cbox]", function (e) {   
//do something
});
```

Comment: I am sure that it would be work, but need more generic way as some classes will not be start with `cbox` in my page. Anyway Thanks and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=checkbox].cbox1, input[type=checkbox].cbox2").on("change",  function (e){

    }) ;
```

Comment: Here you aren't delegating event